# How to make a borderless TopMost form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a borderless form with TopMost set to true, however it seems to ignore the TopMost setting when there is no border.  With FormBorderStyle set to none other (non-TopMost) windows cover it up.

Any simple solutions to this?

EDIT:

I guess I could share that what I'm trying to accomplish is displaying a number in the corner of the screen that's always visible.  I have a customer that gives cave tours and they want to be able to see how many customers are waiting to go on a tour on screen all the time.  So it's just a tiny box in the corner of the screen.  So if there's a better way to accomplish please share :)

Comment: You may have other TopMost windows covering up yours.

Comment: @Charlie As I mentioned, there are non-TopMost windows covering it up.  Any window will cover it up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tried this and it *does* remain TopMost.

Comment: I've tested it too and same here.

Comment: same here.. no issues at all